# Wi-Fi stopped working on Ubuntu 18.10 with Linux 4.18.0-12

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.10

After Linux upgraded from 4.18.0-11-generic to 4.18.0-12-generic on my Ubuntu 18.10 network connection stopped working and on Wi-Fi settings the message: "No Wi-Fi adapter found" is shown. I can still get the connection working by selecting Linux 4.18.0-11 from the startup menu. I have ASUS Vivobook Flip 15 laptop with no Ethernet adapter available so I must get the connection working either via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS did not work for my laptop because of Wi-Fi adapter was not recognized, but Ubuntu 18.10 did work before this latest upgrade.

Network controller (apparently):
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter

Solution: after disabling secure boot via Asus BIOS utility (boot options, scroll down with touchpad to the secure boot option, disable) and rebooting the Wi-Fi adapter started working.

Thanks, @chili555

I noticed this has already been reported as a bug here: [RTL8822BE WiFi Disabled in Kernel 4.18.0-12](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472)

Comment: When you are booted into the later kernel, does the driver load? `lsmod | grep 8822` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep 8822` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: lsmod | grep 8822 for 4.18.0-12 was empty, for 4.18.0-11 it was: `r8822be               860160  0
mac80211              794624  1 r8822be
cfg80211              663552  2 mac80211,r8822be`

dmesg | grep 8822 for 4.18.0.12 apparently contained only Bluetooth information but for 4.18.0-11:
`r8822be: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
r8822be 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
r8822be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin
r8822be: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
r8822be 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
` @chili555

Comment: While booted into -12, load the module and check the log: `sudo modprobe r8822be && dmesg | grep 8822` I suspect we'll see an interesting clue.

Comment: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted`

Comment: You did use sudo, correct? Does the module exist in your -12 version? `sudo updatedb && locate r8822be.ko`

Comment: Yes, I did. And the driver seems to exist but has changed since -11: 

`/lib/modules/4.18.0-10-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko`

`/lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko`

`/lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1489240 oct 23 19:59 /lib/modules/4.18.0-11-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko` 
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1490264 nov 14 15:30 /lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko`

Comment: Please boot into -12 and run: `lsmod`. Paste the result and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J8NCvXKsMN/

Comment: No help there :-( Let's also see: `dmesg` Please paste as above.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XzxsCtjz9r/

Comment: Please try with Secure Boot turned off. Also are there any further clues from `sudo modprobe -v r8822be` That is, -v for verbose.

Comment: I'm not sure if secure boot can be disabled... Asus graphical setup utility displays a disabled CSM option that cannot be enabled. The sudo modprobe -v r8822be command output: `insmod /lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko ` 
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Your *dmesg* says: "[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot enabled
[    0.000000] Kernel is locked down from EFI secure boot; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.0.0 present." Please check in the BIOS/EFI.

Comment: Finally found the secure boot option (it was quite hidden) and disabled it - and Wi-Fi started working. :) But why does that newer kernel require disabling the secure boot when the older one doesn't?

Comment: Please see my answer below. It will probably help others if you accept it so they can find and use the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Marked the answer as useful but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for it to be shown.

Comment: How to accept an answer: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found, by investigation, that secure boot was turned on in your BIOS but that turning it off restored the wireless.

In the standard Ubuntu installation, all modules are supposed to be signed, therefor satifying secure boot. It appears that r8822be is either not signed or is improperly signed. I suggest that you register and file a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: It seemed to be reported already: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be more complex. I've just updated kernel in 18.04 to 4.18 generic and it's having similar issues (although driver is loaded and `ip a` shows the interface as down)

Looking at ifquery it seems wlps03 is not registered, despite showing in `ip a` I'm just going back to older 4.x kernel, but weirdly plugging in ethernet brings up WiFi & ethernet.

This is with an realtek WiFi+gigabit ethernet (shakes fist at realtek).

I also checked lsmod, WiFi driver is loaded...